# Action Bar Sherlock Disappears once the activity loads

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My ActionBar tabs are disappearing when I start an activity from them. I can see the Activity all right, but the tabs don't appear.

My SherlockFragmentActivity is -

```
public class FragmentDemoActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();

    tab1.setText("Fragment A");
    tab2.setText("Fragment B");

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    bar.addTab(tab1);
    bar.addTab(tab2);
}

private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(tab.getPosition()==0)
        {
            CalendarViewActivity frag = new CalendarViewActivity();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CalendarViewActivity.class));
            //ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);

        }
        else
        {
            TestActivity frag = new TestActivity();
            //ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

While my Acitivity is a normal Android Activity -

```
public class CalendarViewActivity extends Activity
```

Any help please.

while my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see the Activity all right, but the tabs don't appear.

Of course not. You did not put any tabs on `CalendarViewActivity`, in part because `CalendarViewActivity` is just a regular `Activity`.

If you are thinking that tapping on a tab should load something into `FragmentDemoActivity`, then you should not be calling `startActivity()` from your `TabListener`. Instead, you should be executing a `FragmentTransaction` or otherwise modifying the UI of `FragmentDemoActivity`.

Comment: Yeah I got the Idea. I was not reading the API properly. Got it working by converting my Activity to Fragment. Thanks.